# Using functions from .so file on Windows in python

Tags: python

So I’ve got an xxx.so file that I created on my Ubuntu machine. Now I’m in need of using that file on Windows machine in python.

Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: Welcome to the bewildering world of non-portable binary executable formats.  No, there is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.so` files are shared objects, usually in the Executable and Linkable Format (ELF). Windows does not have a native loader for ELF; instead, it uses the Portable Executable format (PE). Also, your ELF `.so` is probably compiled for Linux, so it uses Linux system calls.

It is not possible to directly use a Linux binary on Windows. You might consider looking into Windows Subsystem for Linux, which emulates Linux on Windows, but it would probably be easier to recompile the extension module for Windows so that you get a `.dll` file in PE format instead.